# Laravel Sail: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: No address associated with hostname

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

So, I created a project with the latest version of Laravel and Sail and I cannot use the application while DB_HOST is "mysql" (changed by Sail) and I cannot use the sail like (./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate) while the DB_HOST is "localhost".

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_beautiful_db
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

docker-compose.yml (default of Sail)

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

[Image of error: While the BD_HOST is mysql, when I try to use the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRrT0.png)

[Image of error: While the DB_HOST is localhost, the application works but the artisan do not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0PuP.png)

I already try create a new project, creating all the containers again with `./vendor/bin/sail down --rmi all -v`.

I was expecting to be able to use the artisan and the application without have to change the DB_HOST everytime.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: So when your mysql database is in a container, the `DB_HOST` is **not** localhost. It's the ip or hostname of the docker container. Check this link: https://gist.github.com/johanvanhelden/0a9670598fe6ab96c9af7c38c9bcf26a it goes over your running containers and shows the ip of them. Place that and the hostname in your `/etc/hosts` (or your os's equivalent). Then place mysql's hostname in the .env file. In your case it should be `mysql`

Comment: @UnderDog You are absolutely right! I don't recall seeing this step on the docs. I just went to hosts and added "mysql" into 127.0.0.1 and this resolved my problem.

thanks!